# VBA - moving from one cell to another within a defined range

Tags: vba, cells

I have the following task: [VBA Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzQND.png)
I have to enter a rating (number) in each of the table cells in the picture. 
I wrote the code that asks me to enter a value in cell F2, for example (pop up box asks me to enter a value) ! 
But I do not know how to make it go right until J2 and then down to F3 and so on until I fill all the cells with the numbers I want. (See photo in VBA Task)
Here is the code:

Sub GetScore()

```
   Dim QtyEntry As Integer

   Dim Msg As String

   Msg = "Please enter Rating"

   QtyEntry = InputBox(Msg)

   ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value = QtyEntry

  End Sub
```

Could you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.. what values you want in the other cells? The same as you enter in the Inputbox for F2? Or do you want a loop asking for all cell values?

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets(1).Range("F2:J3")
Dim c As Range
For Each c In r.Cells
  c.Value = InputBox("Set value for: " & c.Address)
Next
```

Comment: Yeah, so in the box asking me to fill in a Number I can put any number I want. For example in F2 I want to put 4 and then it should move to F3 and ask me for another Number I want to insert! So i decide what number to put the code should only move the box within a predefined range of cells! Sorry for not being clear and thank you!

Comment: So yeah, it could be a loop, I never did a loop before, the thing is I have to insert numbers cell by cell within a certain range, because each number I insert could be different from the previous. Thank you!

Comment: OK, so this is a new code or I add it to the code I wrote? Thank you!

Comment: WOW! It works! Perfect! Thank you very much! Now let me see if I can create the button command just to move things faster ... Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Now I have problems with the button! I've tried to add a button from Developer in excel but when I click it nothing happens! Do you have any suggestion to what I should do? Thank you!

Comment: I have the feeling you don't really know what you are doing. If you want something to happen when you click on a button you need to do assign a macro to it. Do you use ActiveX Commandbutton or Form Control Button?